# Static int in function

Tags: c++, function, static

I came across this code:

```
void function(int nextFoo)
{
    static int lastFoo = nextFoo; 
    if (nextFoo != lastFoo) 
    {
         // is this possible?
    }
    lastFoo = nextFoo;
}
```

The coder thinks that `lastFoo` is only set in the first run, and the last line, is he right? I think (but don't know) that the code in the if block is never run, but can't find verification of that.

Comment: `nextFoo` is set by the caller... perhaps you're talking about when `lastFoo` is set?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yep, oops, fixed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The coder thinks that nextFoo is only set in the first run, and the last line, is he right?

Yes. `static` local variables are initialized only once (and not every time the function is entered). In C++11, this is also guaranteed to happen in a thread-safe manner. Per paragraph 6.7/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] If control enters
>   the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for
>   completion of the initialization [...]

Notice, that if the initialization of the `static` object throws an exception, its initialization will be re-attempted the next time `function()` is entered (not relevant in this case, since the initialization of an `int` cannot throw). From the same paragraph quoted above:

> [...] If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization
>   is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration. [...]

Comment: _and the last line_ it will set each time the function is called.

Comment: @MM.: Yes, but each time you can call the function with a different argument

Comment: Does anyone know which compilers have implemented the new concurrency requirements?

Answer (score 4):

Of course it's possible. The static initialization happens only **once**. Next time you call the function, the initialization is no longer performed.

(In fact, the initialization is even race-free :-).)

Answer (score 3):

The code in the block *can* run; the following example prints `hello`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void function(int nextFoo)
{
    static int lastFoo=nextFoo; 
    if (nextFoo!=lastFoo) 
    {
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
    lastFoo=nextFoo;
}

int main()
{
    function(1);
    function(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that yes `lastFoo` will only be set the first time here:

```
static int lastFoo=nextFoo;
```

but this would have sufficed as a test to find out how it worked for yourself. Of course at the end of the function `lastFoo` will be set by the final assignment:

```
#include <iostream>

void function(int nextFoo)
{
    static int lastFoo=nextFoo; 

    std::cout << "lastFoo: " << lastFoo << std::endl ;

    if (nextFoo!=lastFoo) 
    {
         std::cout << "here" << std::endl ;
    }
    lastFoo=nextFoo;
}

int main()
{
    function(10) ;
    function(11) ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Static is a storage class and tells the compiler that the variable is not an automatic variable that gets created / destroyed each time the the function is entered and left.

From K&R C Programming Language (2nd Edition)

> A4.1 Storage Class
>
> There are two storage classes: automatic and static
>
> ...
>
> Static objects may be local to a block or external to all blocks, but
>   in either case retain their values across exit from and reentry to functions and blocks.

So yes, the `if` statement is totally legitimate. The variable could have a different value when the function is called again.